# How do i get rid of this eslint error: Component definition is missing display name

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I have an HOC i'm exporting and I'm getting this eslint error:

> Component definition is missing display name

What can I do to resolve it?

My file:

```
import React from 'react';

export const withTags = Component => dataId => props => (
  <Component {...props} data-id={dataId} />
);

export default withTags;
```